# How to select first time from this given set of values

Tags: mysql

Hi everyone i have this time column with data like this

```
time    |
------- |
9:17:19 |
9:17:23 |
9:17:28 |
9:17:33 |
9:17:38 |
9:18:03 |
9:18:08 |
9:18:13 |
9:18:18 |
9:19:03 | 
9:19:13 |
9:19:59 |
9:20:04 |
9:20:59 |
9:21:04 |
9:21:09 |
9:21:54 |
9:21:59 |
9:22:04 |
9:22:09 |
```

from this column my result should be from every Minute  i want first time like

```
9:17:19 |
9:18:03 |
9:19:03 |
9:20:04 |
9:21:04 |
9:22:04 |
```

if any mistakes please forgive me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `time` has the TIME datatype:

```
  SELECT MIN(time)
    FROM table
GROUP BY LEFT(time,5)
ORDER BY time;
```

OR less filthy:

```
  SELECT MIN(time)
    FROM table
GROUP BY HOUR(time), MINUTE(time)
ORDER BY time;
```

Comment: @ArockDVinz `GROUP BY LEFT(time,5)` groups by the first 5 characters of the time (includes just hour and minute).. and the minimum time is selected from each group.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this

```
SELECT MIN(Time) 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY HOUR(time),MINUTE(Time)
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/952db/1)**

Comment: result  i get is first time i.e i am getting 09:17:19 only

Answer (score 0):

Simple, it is:

```
 select * from table_name group by concat(hour(`time`), minute(`time`));
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you added some explaination to your intension.

Comment: This appears to work on the current dataset, but will return an undetermined row from each group, not the minimum time.

Comment: Yes, it should be `select min(time)`.